# JAXB / Java 1.6 / Non-printable characters

Tags: java, jaxb

**Background**: I'm reading a file structure on different old OS (Aix, HP-UX...) and turn some path- and file-information into an XML document.

Problem: Sometimes, there are paths/files named with non-printable characters, for example (listed with `ls -b`):

`important_document\033[D\033[-`

These paths/file names are put into a string held by an object which in turn is marshalled into an XML document like so (`writer` is ):

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Inventory.class);
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
marshaller.marshal(inventory, writer);
```

The marshaller doesn't complain about the unprintable characters and happily creates the XML document, which is rejected by other tools as invalid XML.

**Question**: Is there any way to make the marshaller encode non-printable characters in the output?

I could clean the path/file name but I'd rather it happened document-wide without me having to clean all the individual data points.

Comment: You should fix your filenames instead... As a start, get a list of them: `find . -exec ls -bd {} \; | fgrep '\'`

Comment: They're not my files nor my systems so I can't modify them in anyway.